# PouchDB over HTTP disconnects on inactivity after some minutes?

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I am trying to create an application that uses PouchDB as an adapter to a CouchDB running on a server.

Problem: After some minutes of inactivity I get the following error on trying to access the database again:

> {
> "error": "unauthorized",
> "reason": "You are not authorized to access this db.",
> "status": 401,
> "name": "unauthorized",
> "message": "You are not authorized to access this db.",
> "docId": "category:aktien"
> }

My feeling is, that the HTTP-Connection between Pouch and Couch has a timeout... what can I do about that?

I cant find a "signal" that informs me about the timeout, so I could reconnect. Is there any?

Best Regards,
Tobias

Comment: What authentication scheme is used? Session cookies or Basic?

Comment: I think session based:
    const request = await fetch(sessionUrl, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name: username,
        password: password,
      }),
    });

Comment: I see where you are going... just found the documentation about the Cookie-Lifetime: https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/server/authn.html#api-auth-session and https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/config/auth.html#chttpd_auth/allow_persistent_cookies. Thanks for the advice -- I'll try!

Comment: If you found the solution to your question, you should post the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the settings of CouchDB you can set the session timeout... default is 10 minutes (600 s).